# How to set the pitch, yaw, roll of a quaternion relative to the world

Tags: c++, glm-math

So I have a quaternion that stores the orientation of an object and I have functions to change the pitch, yaw and roll of the quaternion like so:

```cpp
void pitch(float amount)
{
    orientation *= glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(amount), glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
}

void yaw(float amount)
{
    orientation *= glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(-amount), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
}

void roll(float amount)
{
    orientation *= glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(amount), glm::vec3(0, 0, -1));
}
```

What I want to do is set the pitch, yaw and roll relative to the world instead of adding to the current orientation. What I mean by that is right now, say I have a roll of 90*. Each time I use my pitch function and pass 45* into it, the roll will turn into 135* then 180* and so on.
What I want the set pitch function to do is when I pass 45* into it, it will set the roll of the quaternion to 45* and still keep the pitch and yaw.

I made a better explanation in my comment below.

> So to picture what I'm trying to do, imagine 4 walls around you with pictures hanging of an arrow pointing to the world up. What I want to do is no matter what the pitch, yaw and roll of the quaternion, if I'm looking at any of the hanging pictures (any yaw) but with a little roll (so the arrow will point anywhere but up). If I use the setRoll function and pass 0*, the object should see the arrow pointing up. If I pass 90* to the setRoll function, no matter how many times I call the function it should set the object's rotation to 90* so the arrow will point to the left.

---

Thanks to Thomas' answer, I now have this code, but sadly it still doesn't work correctly:

```cpp
void Camera::setPitch(float amount)
{
    glm::vec3 globalUp = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glm::vec3 globalRight = glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    // "The pitch is the angle between the front vector and the horizontal plane. This is pi/2 minus the angle between the front vector and the global up vector."
    float currentPitch = 3.14f / 2.0f -  glm::acos(glm::dot(direction, globalRight));
    // "To find the angle over which you need to rotate, compute the current pitch, and subtract this from the target pitch."
    amount = currentPitch - amount;
    // "To set the pitch without affecting roll and yaw, you'll want to rotate around an axis that lies in the horizontal plane and is orthogonal to the front vector. For a vector to lie in a plane, it means that it's orthogonal to the plane's normal, so we're looking for a vector that is orthogonal to both the global up vector and the front vector. That's just the cross product of the two."
    glm::quat rotation = glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(amount), glm::cross(globalUp, direction));
    orientation *= rotation;


    updateCameraVectors();
    updateViewMatrix();
}

void Camera::setYaw(float amount)
{
    glm::vec3 globalUp = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glm::vec3 globalRight = glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    // "The yaw is the angle between the projection of the front vector onto the global horizontal plane, and some global "zero yaw" vector that also lies in the global horizontal plane. To project the front vector onto the global horizontal plane, simply set its vertical coordinate to zero."
    float currentYaw = 3.14f / 2.0f -  glm::acos(glm::dot(direction, globalRight));
    // "To find the angle over which to rotate, compute the current yaw and subtract this from the target yaw."
    amount = currentYaw - amount;
    // "To change the yaw, simply rotate around the global up vector."
    glm::quat rotation = glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(amount), globalUp);
    orientation *= rotation;
    // "Note that yaw is ill-defined when looking straight up; in that case, you can maybe set the roll instead, because the two are essentially the same."
    // TODO...


    updateCameraVectors();
    updateViewMatrix();
}

void Camera::setRoll(float amount)
{

    glm::vec3 globalUp = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    // "The roll is the angle between the local right vector and the global up vector, minus pi/2"
    float currentRoll =  glm::acos(glm::dot((right, globalUp)) - 3.14f / 2.0f;
    // "To find the angle over which to rotate, compute the current roll and subtract this from the target roll."
    amount = currentRoll - amount;
    // "To change the roll, you'll want to rotate around the local front vector."
    glm::quat rotation = glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(amount), direction);
    orientation *= rotation;

    updateCameraVectors();
    updateViewMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to keep your original rotation in Euler angles (pitch/yaw/roll) and only convert them to a matrix when you want to transform something.

Comment: Hello @Thomas! I'm trying to make a space game where the spaceship and camera can move on all axis and I was told to use quaternions and I think that is what I want, could Euler angles do the same? With quaternions I know if you mix pitch and yaw it adds a little roll, and I like that. Would Euler angles do the same?

Comment: In space, all directions are equivalent, so quaternions are a good choice. But what does "relative to the world" mean then? You could try reversing the order of the rotations, i.e. `orientation = glm::angleAxis(...) * orientation;`, but I'm not sure that's what you mean.

Comment: Glad to know quaternions are what I'm looking for! Reversing the order of the rotations doesn't do what I'm trying to achieve, but I see another nice use of reversing the order like that.

Comment: So to picture what I'm trying to do, imagine 4 walls around you with pictures hanging of an arrow pointing to the world up. What I want to do is no matter what the pitch, yaw and roll of the quaternion, if I'm looking at any of the hanging pictures (any yaw) but with a little roll (so the arrow will point anywhere but up). If I use the setRoll function and pass 0*, the object should see the arrow pointing up. If I pass 90* to the setRoll function, no matter how many times I call the function it should set the object's rotation to 90* so the arrow will point to the left.

Answer (score 2):

So here's my understanding of what you're trying to do. You have a unit quaternion `orientation`. You can picture this as a "front" vector pointing out from your eyes, and an "up" vector pointing out of the top of your head. From these follows a "right" vector pointing out your right ear.

You didn't explain your coordinate system, so I'll keep this in pretty generic terms. And this post is more of a "how to think about the problem" rather than working code, but I hope that's at least as useful in the long term.

#### Pitch

The pitch is the angle between the front vector and the horizontal plane. This is pi/2 minus the angle between the front vector and the global up vector.

To set the pitch without affecting roll and yaw, you'll want to rotate around an axis that lies *in* the horizontal plane and is orthogonal to the front vector. For a vector to lie in a plane, it means that it's orthogonal to the plane's normal, so we're looking for a vector that is orthogonal to both the global up vector and the front vector. That's just the cross product of the two.

To find the angle over which you need to rotate, compute the current pitch, and subtract this from the target pitch.

#### Yaw

The yaw is the angle between the projection of the front vector onto the global horizontal plane, and some global "zero yaw" vector that also lies in the global horizontal plane. To project the front vector onto the global horizontal plane, simply set its vertical coordinate to zero.

To change the yaw, simply rotate around the global up vector.

To find the angle over which to rotate, compute the current yaw and subtract this from the target yaw.

Note that yaw is ill-defined when looking straight up; in that case, you can maybe set the roll instead, because the two are essentially the same.

#### Roll

The roll is the angle between the local right vector and the global up vector, minus pi/2.

To change the roll, you'll want to rotate around the *local* front vector.

To find the angle over which to rotate, compute the current rol and subtract this from the target roll.

Comment: I'll have to test this in the morning, but it sounds like exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: So I was able to get this far with translating your answer to code:
I think I understand what you mean and the only issue I have is finding the angle between two vectors, how can I do that?

Edit: The code is too big so I edited it to my question

Comment: I would assume that `glm` has a function for this. If not: the formula is `acos(dot(normalize(a), normalize(b)))`. If one or both of these vectors is already normalized, you can of course omit the normalization.

Comment: Sadly my code doesn't seem to give the expected results... If I call just the setPitch function once every frame (and I don't call any other orientation-changing functions), and  pass the setPitch function 5.0f, what I expected was for the pitch to be set to 5.0f every frame but what happens is the pitch is still moving by +5.0f every frame. Same happens with all the other set functions. I did notice that if I set the roll to 0.0f, it still rotates the camera a little bit if I add a little pitch or yaw.

Comment: I uploaded a mostly stripped down version of my program to dropbox in-case you or someone else can help find the issue. Sorry I have lots of messy code and the program will only work on windows.
[Download Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2trbept7ainm7yx/ReproducingABug.zip?dl=0)